# android regex and decimal format

Tags: regex, decimalformat

I have a column Number(9,4) in database. I want to send to column data that entered edittext.

I must control format 123456789.1234 and control only number and dot.

I find regex for number and dot but i don't have decimal format control. User can't enter 123.12345 or 1234567891.1

How can i do this ?

My regex is :

```
"^*[0-9\\.]+$"
```

Edittext control code is:

```
        txtTabelaEni.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            String text = txtTabelaEni.getText().toString();
            if (text.length() > 0) {
                if (!text.substring(text.length() - 1).matches(regexStr))
                {
                    txtTabelaEni.setText(text.substring(0, text.length() - 1));
                    txtTabelaEni.setSelection(txtTabelaEni.length());
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int b, int c){ }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int st, int c, int a){ }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I must control format 123456789.1234 and control only number and dot.

You can use this regex in Java:

```
String re = "^\\d{0,9}\\.\\d{1,4}$"
```

In case you want to make decimal part optional then use:

```
String re = "^(\\d{0,9}\\.\\d{1,4}|\\d{1,9})$"
```

Comment: i can't entry number with this regex ?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand your comment, can you clarify?

Comment: when i use your regex in my edittext, I can't write dot(.) and can write 12345678912. I don't want to write more than nine characters to dot

Comment: [As you can see in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xS1mO4/1) then this regex is working correctly and `12345678912` is not accepted.

Comment: `final String regexStr = "^(\d{0,9}\.\d{1,4}|\d{1,9})$";`

I have red line warning under regex string?

Comment: @mobileprogramming You need to escape the backslashes. `\d` should be `\\d`. Otherwise the Java compiler will try to find an escape sequence for d.

Comment: @mobileprogramming: I've already provided you correct regex in my answer `String re = "^(\\d{0,9}\\.\\d{1,4}|\\d{1,9})$";`

Comment: @anubhava when I use `String re = "^(\\d{0,9}\\.\\d{1,4}|\\d{1,9})$";`
and use my edittext control code, I can write 1234567891234
my edittext control code is warning ?
When i test your URL, it works but in my code is problem

Comment: Okay I worked it. I seperately controlled it. 1- Only number and dot. 2- #########.####

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
\d+($|(\.($|\d+$)))
```

It looks for a sequence of digits, then one of:

```
end of string - matches 123
a dot and end of string - matches 123.
a dot and more digits and then end of string - matches 1234.45
```

A with a letter after it won't be matched